# c++ using functions within functions

Tags: c++, function, set

I am new to c++ but I am working on a project dealing with doing different operations with sets and one of them simply prints it out if the set is finite. SoS is the object being used which just stands for set of strings and has a vector of strings and a boolean as its data members. I created a function to check if the set is finite and I am trying to call it in my print function but i keep getting an error saying "no member named "isFinite." Heres what I have, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
void SoS::print() const{
    if (m_vos.isFinite() == true){
        for (int i = 0; i < m_vos.size(); i++){
            cout << m_vos[i]<< endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "COMPLEMENT OF:"<< endl;
        for (int i = 0; i< m_vos.size(); i++){
            cout << m_vos[i]<< endl;
        }
    }
}

bool SoS::isFinite() const{
    if (isfinite(m_vos.size()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it saying `no member named "isFinite"` or is it saying `no member named "isfinite"`? In your `isFinite` method you make a call to `isfinite`. Also `isFinite` doesn't have any parameters. And if your first line of a method calls said method, you'll get an infinite recursion.

Comment: What is `m_vos`? It looks like a member of `SoS` but doesn't appear to be a pointer. You need to call `SoS::isFinite()` on an object of `SoS`, or you can call it from within another method of `SoS`.

Comment: @Tas `m_vos` could be a value-member, not all objects need pointers to use them.

Comment: But in order for it to be of type `SoS`, declared in `SoS`, it would need to be a pointer right? Unless it was a global?

Comment: @Tas The OP wrote that `SoS` contains a "vector of strings and a boolean as its data members". So `vector<string> m_vos;`

Comment: Yes m_vos is the vector of strings and the error im getting is with "isFinite" not "isfinite"

Comment: It appears then that you are trying to call `isFinite()`, a member of `SoS`, on a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Why not just use `if (isfinite(m_vos.size())) { ... }` instead of `if (m_vos.isFinite() == true) { ... }`? The latter will give you an error since `std::vector` has no member named `isFinite()`.

Comment: I would do that but the project requires an isFinite function as it is used in other parts of the program. This is what I was given and told to implement bool isFinite() const ;
Return true if the host object is a finite set and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to call `SoS::isFinite()` on a `std::vector<std::string>` (`m_vos`). `std::vector` has no such member. You can only call `SoS::isFinite()` on an object of type `SoS` or within a `SoS` function.

Fortunately you are within a `SoS` function, so you can simply change your code to:

```
void SoS::print() const{
    // Calls SoS::isFinite()
    if (isFinite() == true){
```

Answer (score 4):

C++, like C, requires forward declaration due to the nature of its single-pass compiler design. In C++ this isn't usually a problem as a class is fully declared in the header file before the .cpp file, but that error message suggests you haven't fleshed-out your class declaration.

It should look like this (according to your description):

```
class SoS {
private:
    vector<string> m_vos;
    bool someBool;
public:
    void print() const;
    bool isFinite() const;
}
```

Comment: OP will also need `bool isfinite(param)` in his header file as well, unless it's declared globally or in the same namespace.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Not necessarily, `isinfinite` could be a global function.

Comment: If `m_vos` is indeed a `std::vector<std::string>`, it would be an error to call `m_vos.isFinite()`, so the problem would be "no member named `isFinite()`" in `std::vector`

Comment: @Tas Ah, I missed that call at the beginning of the `print` function. I don't know. We'll have to wait until the OP gives more details.

Comment: isfinite within my isFinite function is coming from #include <math.h>.